# Developing for FB, can't find a good tutorial- what tutorials HELPED YOU?

Tags: ajax, facebook, fbml

Please spare me the google answers, I've been googling all weekend (and off and on previous to that) to find good tutorials and I can't find any.

It seems that everything I've found on FBML is VERY outdated or SIMPLY just a helloworld (which is REALLY REALLY basic).

I currently do a lot in ajax and php, but making the transition to FBML is not clicking with me.

So I'm wondering - what tutorials WORKED FOR YOU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find most fresh book about fbml. The reason is that fb has been changing their api constantly. But you should still read a book about fbml to get you started. Once you know what is what, you can then keep yourself updated with latest fbml and api happenings.

I find the book:

**FBML Essentials: Facebook Markup Language Fundamentals**

to be really good. And luckily i have found a free download link for that:

[You can download it here](http://knowfree.net/2008/12/fbml-essentials-facebook-markup-language-fundamentals/)

Thanks

Comment: THANK YOU! I ordered FB for dummies off amazon (used for a good price) to have a hard copy just in case... you COMPLETELY affirmed what I felt I would need to do, but I was afraid to bark up the wrong tree!

Comment: that was the way and that is great news :)